# How to build a skype-like small video chat window (multiscreen)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, qt, unity-game-engine, multiscreen

I am trying to build a small video chat window which can co-exist on the screen with other application such as internet browser like which is shown in this picture

[image]

My main problem is not with  WEBRTC but with how to make two applications co-exist on the screen as skype does.

I have some experience with unity , rails and node.js . Is there any chance I can achieve my goal with the above framework?

Or do I have to learn something new like QT?

Please give me some advice, thanks a lot.

p.s. Do I have to build a desktop app for this feature or a website would be able to do the trick?

Comment: Is that in-browser skype?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev  I am not sure if I could do it in-browser or do I have to build an desktop app for it.    It would be better to do it in-browser . Just not sure how to achieve that

Answer (score 0):

Unity has decent webcam support which insists that it supports webGL(html5).

You might want to check links below.

- https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WebCamDevice.html
- [WebGL webcam update](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/12/07/unity-5-3-webgl-updates/)
- [how to setup(unity question forum)](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/909967/getting-a-web-cam-to-play-on-ui-texture-image.html)